# When and where to unregister messenger with mvvmlight

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, messenger

I build a project with mvvmlight. Using Messenger send message between VMs or VM and View. Now, I wonder that when and where to unregister messenger. Could u help me?

**Edited:**

This is my scene:

There are a MainWindow and a ChildWindow, the ChildWindow (include a ContentControl consist of one of two different UserControl), change the ContenControl via a SwitchButton in ChildWindow. Every window or UserControl corresponding to a ViewModel.

[image]

1. `MainViewModel` sends a message to `MainWindow` to open the `ChildWindow`;
2. `MainWindow` opens the `ChildWindow` (firstly use `UserControlView1`, don't use `UserControlView2`), and send a message to `UserControl1ViewModel` do something;
3. If user click the CancelButton, `ChildWindowViewModel` sends a message to `ChildWindow` to close;
4. If `ChildWindowViewModel` fire `UnloadedCommand`, `ChildWindow` sends a message to each of `UserControlViewmodel` to clean up something.

The operation of register and unregister messenger put in the constructor and the destructor of the View or the ViewModel, or put in the LoadedCommand and UnloadedCommand's delegate methods? View's Loaded and Unloaded's command binding to LoadedCommand and UnloadedCommand.

Comment: Mine sit in the constructor, and I don't really unregister them, since I don't need them "unregistered". What is your reason for unregistering them?

Comment: um, I see somebody said that unregister messenger may be better in stackoverflow. I'm unsure about that.